# What does H/F, M/F and M/W abbreviation in job titles mean?

Tags: abbreviations

If you look at some job titles on [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) you can come across several abbreviations: H/F, M/F, M/W. It does not look programming specific (excuse me if I'm wrong). E.g.:

> Ruby-on-Rails or AngularJS developer for Open Source project
>   (m/f)
>
> Senior PHP Developer (m/f)
>
> PHP Softwareentwickler (m/w)
>
> Team Leader Web .Net (H/F)

What is their meaning?

Comment: This a bit of a guess but M/F and M/W could be Male/Female and Man/Woman - H/F (if you were in France) could be Homme/Femme.

Comment: Guess you are right. Cause 'Team Leader Web .Net (H/F) - EDITEUR - Management d’équipe – Pôle Innovation
TRACE ONE
Paris, France'

Comment: In the examples you give, _m/f_ is certainly _male/female_, and it refers to the noun _developer_ in both cases. The other abbreviations may mean something similar if they are used in similar ways, but we cannot know that because you provide us no examples of how they are used.

Comment: The one case of _m/w_ given is in a German posting, so it probably stands for _männlich/weiblich_, the German counterpart to _male/female_.

Comment: Related meta question: [Should we disallow gender indication in Careers job postings?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145254/should-we-disallow-gender-indication-in-careers-job-postings)

Comment: Also on the Workplace: [Why are places specifying “(m/f)” in the job title?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59664/why-are-places-specifying-m-f-in-the-job-title)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343471/what-does-m-f-mean-in-job-description-titles

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is used primarily for job postings from countries which use languages with different words for the masculine and feminine job titles (like English actor/actress, sculptor/scupltress, dominator/dominatrix, etc). Appending "m/f" or similar is a concise way to indicate that applicants of any gender are welcome. It may be a legal requirement in some of these jurisdictions, so has to appear in English even when though it is typically irrelevant.

So these abbreviations stand for:

- M/F - Male/Female
- M/W (if you were in Germany) Männlich/Weiblich
- H/F (if you were in France) - Homme/Femme

Comment: For almost all jobs in Britain, the "legal requirement" is that the position must be open to applicants regardless of gender, so there's no reason to explicitly state this in a recruitment advert. Personally, I'd be leery of working for any company who thought they might need to actually point out the they comply with the law in respect of such a basic point.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it reflects more a misunderstanding of how to translate from a "genderful" language to a gender less one like English. I can see how someone from a German-speaking country, likely a bureaucrat, might think this is necessary to indicate that both male and female applicants are welcome to apply when the posting is translated into English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I believe the idea is that for languages that have separate words for the male and female job titles, *even if* it is already legally required for the job to be open to all applicants regardless of gender, it is thought that using only the masculine title might give a female applicant the false impression that she would not be eligible, or that the company would prefer a man. (Just as if an advert in English talked about the applicant using supposedly "epicene" male pronouns.)

Comment: @sumelic: Offhand I can't think of a job title still in common use that might be seen as "gender-specific" (stereotypes like *nurse = female* having been put out to grass decades ago). Reed, one of the big recruitment agencies in the UK, say [*Avoid gender-specific language, such as ‘male only’ or ‘female only’, and keep all terminology neutral. This also applies to job titles. So instead of recruiting a ‘Handy Man’, go for ‘Handy Person’ and you’ll avoid any potential headaches with the HR department.*](http://news.reed.co.uk/tips-for-avoiding-discrimination-in-job-adverts/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: yes, but in languages like German most job titles are the equivalent of "Handy Man," with no gender-neutral equivalent. You can list the full title in both genders, "Handy Man or Handy Woman," but that's a bit long. To save space, you might say "Handy (Wo)man," or "Handy Man (m/f)." Anyway, this is a practice that makes sense in other languages, so gets carried over by accident to English in some cases. But note that the OP's third example is not in English but in German ("Softwareentwickler" is masculine and traditionally epicene, "Softwareentwicklerin" is the feminine form).

Comment: @sumelic: But ELU isn't a site for learning about *German*. Nor, to be honest, do I think it's a site for explaining how to translate something from German to English *taking account of any cultural differences*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yeah. I just think you were pretty unfair on the companies in your first comment. In that cultural/linguistic context, listing both genders is a fairly standard practice that's actually meant to *avoid* gender-specific language; it's basically equivalent to the practices recommended by Reed. If you think the original question is off-topic now that you know the answer, you can vote to close.

Comment: @sumelic: I don't know what *now that you know the answer* is supposed to imply. If I saw this Q when it was first posted (which I really can't remember) I probably closevoted without bothering to comment. But the fact that it's still hanging around nearly a year later suggests there's no support for my position anyway.

Comment: I've read that this is to comply with German laws. Everyone seems to have this suffix on their listings for German companies.

Comment: Then what about these?

Senior iOS Engineer - (M/F/X),  iOS DEVELOPER (m/f/d),  Germany

Comment: @RandikaVishman, that is probably to indicate that they will accept individuals who identify as male, female, or neither.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod, "D" meaning?

Comment: D is different. I think it is for Disabled. https://work.chron.com/m-f-d-v-stand-end-job-description-10093.html